# How to organize hierarchical structure in custom post type with taxonomy (like with categories)

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, taxonomy

can anyone help me with  custom post type arhive? I want there organise taxonomy term structure like with categories.

Full image url: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzl4y.png

[image]